# How do I preserve newlines in CouchDB attachments?

Tags: curl, couchdb, newline

I'm saving CSV-formatted files as attachments in CouchDB, but when I retrieve them the newlines are missing.  What should I do differently to preserve the newlines?

```
% cat -vet foo.csv
line1-field1, line1-field2, line1-field3$
line2-field1, line2-field2, line2-field3$  

% curl -X PUT -H "Content-type: text/csv" -d @foo.csv $SERVER/testdb/testdoc/foo
{"ok":true,"id":"testdoc","rev":"1-fe07e847a7934a14055890ff3d8f5603"}

% curl -X GET $SERVER/testdb/testdoc/foo |cat -vet
line1-field1, line1-field2, line1-field3line2-field1, line2-field2, line2-field3%
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that curl is striping newlines for some reason. I've managed to avoid it by forcing binary:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-type: text/csv" --data-binary @foo.csv $SERVER/testdb/testdoc/foo
```

Comment: This is curl's behaviour and has nothing to do with CouchDB. CouchDB does not tamper with attachment data (aside from transparently compressing and decompressing it for compressible data)